# Селекторы jQuery

Tags: jquery

Не понимаю почему событие не вешается на тэг `<li>`. То есть срабатывает только первый селектор.

```
$("a").live("click",function(){
    var this_href=this.href;
    $.get(this_href+"&popUp=AJAX", function(content){
        $(".block4 .section").html(content);
    });
    return false;
});

$(".block3_menu li").live("click", function(){
    var id=$("a", this).attr("id");
    var this_href=$("a",this).attr("href");
    $.get("index.php",{mod: "navigation", id: id, popUp: "AJAX"}, function(htm){
        $("#navigation").html(htm);
        alert(htm);
        $.get(this_href+"&popUp=AJAX", function(content){
            $(".block4 .section").html(content);
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Решил таким образом:**

```
    $("a:not(.block3_menu a)").live("click",function(){
    var this_href=this.href;
    $.get(this_href+"&popUp=AJAX", function(content){
        $(".block4 .section").html(content);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `$(".block3_menu li").live("click", function(){`

Сюда заходит?

Comment: вот именно что нет... там alert(htm) не срабатывает. Если убрать первую часть ($("a").live...) то работает все...

Comment: Добавь `alert` сразу после `live("click", function(){`, а остальное до `return false;` закомментируй.

Я к тому, что либо он не находит элемент по селектору, либо внутри не может что-то сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажисть  я догнал в чем дело. Внутри тэга <li> есть ссылка, то есть тэг <a>, а ссылка прерывается первой конструкцией (return false). Вот и не срабатывает вторая конструкция. Только как быть теперь? Нужно на все ссылки повесить $("a").live..., а на ссылки в меню вторую конструкцию...